# Enable button by event handling

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

Have a tab page with 2 panels, a data grid view and a 'clear' button.There are only textboxes in the panels and the grid is unbound. Data input is by user. The clear btn is disabled by default. My requirement is to enable it **only** if any of the textboxes is not empty or there is more than 1 row in the grid. This code isn't working. Please help.

```
public Form1()
 {
   InitializeComponent();
   foreach (Control c in InvoiceTab.Controls)
    {
      if (c is DataGridView)
       {
         DataGridView dgv = c as DataGridView;
         if (dgv.RowCount > 1)
          {
            EnableClearBtnBool = true;
            btnClear.Enabled = true;
            break;
          }
         else
          {
            EnableClearBtnBool = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = false;
            break;
          }
       }
    }
    foreach (Control c1 in panel1.Controls)
     {
       if (c1 is TextBox)
        {
          if (c1.Text != "")
            {
              EnableClearBtnBool = true;
              c1.TextChanged -= EnableClearBtn;
              c1.TextChanged += EnableClearBtn;
              break;
            }
          else
             EnableClearBtnBool = false;
        }                  
     }
     foreach (Control c2 in panel2.Controls)
      {
        if (c2 is TextBox)
         {
           if (c2.Text != "")
            {
              EnableClearBtnBool = true;
              c2.TextChanged -= EnableClearBtn;
              c2.TextChanged += EnableClearBtn;
              break;
            }
           else
            EnableClearBtnBool = false;
         }
      }      
 }
bool EnableClearBtnBool = false;
private void EnableClearBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EnableClearBtnBool == true)
            btnClear.Enabled = true;
        else
            btnClear.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is almost certainly not working because of its location first and foremost. However, there are some fundamental changes we should be able to make as well. First we're going to need this code in a method that can be called frequently:

```
private void RefreshClearButton()
{
    btnClear.Enabled = textBox1.Text.Length > 0 ||
        textBox2.Text.Length > 0 || ...
        dataGridView.RowCount > 1;
}
```

but, we also need to leverage the `TextChanged` event on **all of the text boxes**:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshClearButton();
}
```

so you need to hook all of them up to this event handler. Now, we have two more events we need to consume, on the `DataGridView`, `RowsAdded` and `RowsRemoved`:

```
private void dataGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshClearButton();
}

private void dataGridView_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshClearButton();
}
```

and so now we're notified every time something changes. If you must iterate through the panels rather than naming every single text box along the way then you might want to do something like this:

```
private bool HasTextBeenEntered(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (var c in controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox && ((TextBox)c).Text.Length > 0) { return true; }
        else if (c is Control && HasTextBeenEntered(((Control)c).Controls)) { return true; }
    }

    return false;
}
```

which would change the `RefreshClearButton` method slightly:

```
private void RefreshClearButton()
{
    btnClear.Enabled = HasTextBeenEntered(this.Controls) || dataGridView.RowCount > 1;
}
```

***DISCLAIMER:*** none of this code is compiled so don't be surprised if you have to tweak it, but it will get you more than 90% of the way.

Comment: @Michael.Thank you very much. The first solution worked.I'm trying to understand how the second works :)